# Powershell writing to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get powershell to write results to AWS S3 and I can't figure out the syntax. Below is the line that is giving me trouble. If I run this without everything after the ">>" the results print on the screen.

```
Write-host "Thumbprint=" $i.Thumbprint " Expiration Date="$i.NotAfter " InstanceID ="$instanceID.Content" Subject="$i.Subject >> Write-S3Object -BucketName arn:aws:s3:::eotss-ssl-certificatemanagement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an issue with `>>` be aware that you can't pass the write-host function result into another command.

In order to do that, you need to assign the string you want into a variable and then pass it into the `-Content`.

Take a look at the following code snippet:

```
    Install-Module AWSPowerShell
    Import-Module AWSPowerShell
    #Set AWS Credential        
    Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey "AccessKey" -SecretKey "SecretKey"        

    #File upload
    Write-S3Object -BucketName "BucketName" -Key "File upload test" -File "FilePath"

    #Content upload
    $content = "Thumbprint= $($i.Thumbprint) Expiration Date=$($i.NotAfter) InstanceID = $($instanceID.Content) Subject=$($i.Subject)"
    Write-S3Object -BucketName "BucketName" -Key "Content upload test" -Content $content
```

How to create new AccessKey and SecretKey - [Managing Access Keys for Your AWS Account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html).

[AWSPowerShell Module installation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-getting-set-up-windows.html)

[AWS Tools for PowerShell - S3 Documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/S3_cmdlets.html)