# Powershell Pipe stdout from s3 cp command to gzip

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, pipe, gzip

Trying to use Powershell on Windows 10 to download a small .gz file from an s3 bucket using the aws s3 cp command.

I am piping the output of the `s3 cp` to `gzip -d` to decompress.  My aim is to basically copy, unzip and display contents without saving the .gz file locally.

From reading the official Amazon documentation for the s3 cp command, the following is mentioned:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

> **Downloading an S3 object as a local file stream**
>
> WARNING:: PowerShell may alter the encoding of or add a CRLF to piped or >redirected output.

Here is the command I'm executing from powershell:

```
PS C:\> aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/test.txt.gz - | gzip -d
```

Which returns the following error: `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`

The command works fine when run from Windows Command Prompt but I just can't seem to get it working with Powershell.

From a Windows Command prompt, it works fine:

```
C:\Windows\system32>aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/test.txt.gz - | gzip -d
```

With some sample test data output as follows:

```
first_name  last_name   
----------  ----------
Ellerey     Place       
Cherie      Glantz      
Isaak       Grazier
```

Comment: as a workaround you can run cmd commands from powershell using `cmd.exe /c "aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/test.txt.gz - | gzip -d"`

Comment: Anyhow, I suggest working with AWS Powershell module which is equivalent to AWS CLI but design to PowerShell usage, take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155183/9931092